# How to add specific files to a wx.TreeCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, treecontrol

I am trying to re-create part of a directory tree by using wx.TreeCtrl. I can add all directories and the specific files I am looking for. Now, I would like to not show the directories that do not contain the specific files.

For example, if my directory tree looks like this and I only want to show .csv files (wx.TreeCtrl root is "/data/project"):

- /data/project/
- /data/project/file.csv
- /data/project/anotherdir/myfile.txt

...then with my current code, my wx.TreeCtrl will include the "anotherdir", without the "myfile.txt". I would like to get to a stage whereby "anotherdir" is not shown at all.

My current Python code looks like this:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(root):
    for dirname in sorted(dirnames):
        fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
        ids[fullpath] = self.MyTree.AppendItem(ids[dirpath], dirname, self.folderidx)

    for filename in sorted(filenames):
        fullfilename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)

        if fullfilename.endswith('.csv'):
            myid = self.MyTree.AppendItem(ids[dirpath], filename, self.csvidx)
```

Thank you for any suggestions.